# CSV upload works with local WAMP but not with remote LAMP using LOAD DATA

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, nginx, permissions

**New:**

Uploading actual .csv file to /tmp folder using WinSCP with correct structure to the server and then running `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` from `mysql` CLI works flawlessly. But if you upload from the form I trigger the "sorry" error. I've echo'ed and var_dumped several global $_FILE variables and here are their results:

**$_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']**:

`dirname` is `/tmp`

`basename` is `php8k4jFN` (*different every-time I run the script and has not .csv ending*)

`filename` is `php8k4jFN`

**Full Filepath:**

`/tmp/php8k4jFN`

**$_FILES['csv']['error']:**

`0`

**Permissions:**

`mysql` and `www-data` are part of `root` group and both are allowed to read/write `/tmp`

Executing `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL...` from `mysql` CLI with a `mycsv.csv` file inside `/tmp` work fine although with some warnings(*could this trigger the error?*).

Removed apparmor and gave root 1775 permission t /tmp

---

My form lets you upload a **CSV** file.

I use `LOAD DATA LOCAl INFILE` to upload CSV's contents into a MySQL table.
Idea is: user uploads a local CSV on his computer to my remote LAMP server using my form.

If I test everything in a local environment(WAMP running on my computer) then everything works correctly. I've ironed out all the syntax, logic and CSV structure errors.

As soon as I upload my entire source to a remote LAMP server and try to upload a CSV from my laptop to it I trigger my custom error: `"Sorry, couldn't upload the CSV"`.

I tested it and I don't get that error locally ever. Later, I had found out that I had to enable `local-infile` inside `my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` and `[mysql]` on the LAMP server to let me use `LOCAL` keyword.

Before I made that change I used to get: `The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`.

I tried to echo the query in my PHP script and execute it manually through mysql command line and got the following error(which makes sense since the temp file doesn't exist anymore): 
`ERROR 2 (HY000): File '/tmp/phpINUea0' not found (Errcode: 2)`

Echo'ed query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/phpINUea0' 
INTO TABLE mydb.suites
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(suite, business_name, business_phone, business_email) 
SET location_id = 2
```

Then I also tried to debug my form with PHP's `echo`, `var_dump` and `print_r` but got empty/false returns from all three statements:

```
$query_add_suite_csv = $this->db_connection->query($query);

echo $query_add_suite_csv;          // returns nothing
var_dump($query_add_suite_csv);     // returns boolean false
print_r($query_add_suite_csv);      // return nothing

if ($query_add_suite_csv) {
    // success message
}else{
    echo "Sorry, couldn't upload the CSV"
}
```

Currently out of ideas as to why this could be happening. In case it matters, I've used [THIS](https://mattwilcox.net/web-development/setting-up-a-secure-home-web-server-with-raspberry-pi) guide to setup my remote LAMP server.

File upload PHP function:

```
private function addSuiteCSV()
{
    if (empty($_POST['suite_location_csv'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Must select location of suite";
    }else{

        // create a database connection
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }

        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
            $suite_location_csv = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['suite_location_csv'], ENT_QUOTES));
            if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) {
                $file = addslashes($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);

                $query =<<<EOF
                    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
                    INTO TABLE mydb.suites
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES
                    (suite, business_name, business_phone, business_email)
                    SET location_id = $suite_location_csv
EOF;

                $query_add_suite_csv = $this->db_connection->query($query);

                if ($query_add_suite_csv) {
                    // success
                } else {
                    // sorry
                }               

            }else{
                // empty file
            }
        }else{
            // db connection error
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tested whether the file is received?

Comment: @frz3993
If I'm not wrong `/tmp` is cleared after every reboot. I haven't rebooted my LAMP server since, and there's nothing inside `/tmp` folder. Therefore I assume it must be safe to say that files are not received. I also tried to upload a file into `/tmp` manually to see if there's a read/write permission issue, but I was able to upload a file without any problems.

Comment: I think file in the `/tmp` file will get deleted after the PHP script finished executing. Try `echo pathinfo($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);` . See if you get anything. Change the filename to your csv file name.

Comment: @frz3993 `echo`ing gave me output of `Array`. I also did `var_dump` on `pathinfo()` and got this: `array(3) { ["dirname"]=> string(4) "/tmp" ["basename"]=> string(9) "php61HnlJ" ["filename"]=> string(9) "php61HnlJ" }`

Comment: That means that file is uploaded to the server. Why don't you try moving the uploaded file to another folder.

Comment: @frz3993 Like where?

Comment: Anywhere, as long as your web server has read/write access for that folder. Usually, I will create and `/upload/` directory in the web root. But careful, don't give execute permission to that folder.

Comment: Your script should work. I think the problem lies elsewhere. Check the `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini or if your file take very long to upload check `max_execution_time` too. You can adjust it in the `php.ini` or you can use `ini_set()` on top of your script.

Comment: @frz3993 All those constants seem to be okay. My CSV files are no bigger than 5KB at most. Execution time is less than a second usually. I changed the `upload_tmp_dir` to `upload` folder inside my website's root folder and now I keep getting empty file error when my script runs. The upload folder has `drwxrwxr-x 2 root root` permission

Comment: Don't change the tmp dir, use `move_uploaded_file()` function instead.  Check for `$_FILES['csv']['error']` value too and web server error log too.

Answer (score 0):

Had to move production to WAMP instead of LAMP. Must have been some unknown to me permission issue with Linux.